# I want to create a new UIWindow in Swift project,but something wrong

Tags: swift, uiwindow

I create a new project in Swift,and I want to create a new UIWindow,here is the code in my controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let myWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        myWindow.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        myWindow.hidden = false


    }
```

when I run the project,I got the message: 'Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch'.But at the Objective-C project,it's OK.

Who can tell me what's wrong whit my project?

Thanks.

Comment: On iOS you don't create windows. What are you trying to achieve? Normally you would have a Storyboard with UIViewControllers. It is the views within ViewControllers that are displayed. There is a UIWindow, but it is behind the scenes and you generally don't need to deal with it.

Comment: @Michael I want to achieve a area-picker in swift，with a dim background.I have ever achieved a actionsheet by create a new window by OC[here is the code](https://github.com/newbbydong/SinaWeiboActionSheet)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by areaPicker. But just create an instance of an areaPicker and add `self.view.addSubview(areaPickerView)`

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I got the answer by myself.You can't create a new UIWindow at the time when loading a new ViewController,but you can do it after the view is loaded.Here is the code:

```
    let myWindow = {Void->UIWindow in
        let cWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        cWindow.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        return cWindow
    }()

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        myWindow.hidden = false
    }
```